# 整数値、実数値の合計をそれぞれ返すプログラムで結果が表示されない

Tags: c

整数値の合計と実数値の合計を表示するプログラムを以下の通り作成したのですが、現状のプログラムでは `整数a,b　実数c,dの値を入力してください` というコメントが出てきただけで、整数値と実数値の合計の結果を表すコメントは表示されませんでした。

恐らくmain関数で何かを間違えたのだと思いますが、間違い部分がよくわからなかったので、おわかりいただければ回答よろしくお願いします。

---

**期待する実行結果 (実行例)**

```
$./a.out
整数aを入力してください：5
整数bを入力してください：7
実数cを入力してください：4.8
実数dを記入してください：5.8
整数値の合計は12です。
実数値の合計は10.600000です。
```

**作成したプログラム**

```
/* 2つの整数値 a, b の和を返す関数 */
int sum_int(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

double sum_double(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, b,ans_int;
    double c, d, ans_double;

  printf("整数aの値を入力してください:" );
    scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("整数bの値を入力してください:" );
    scanf("%d", &b);
 ans_int = sum_int(a, b);

 printf("実数cの値を入力してください:" );
    scanf("%lf", &c);
  printf("実数dの値を入力してください:" );
    scanf("%lf", &d);
   ans_double = sum_double(c, d);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

結果を表示するコードがどこにもないので（加算するコードはあっても）表示されないのは当然の結果でしょう。 `ans_int` と `ans_double` を `printf()` に渡してください。提示例のように表示したいとなるとフォーマット文字だけでなく桁数指定が必要です。とりあえずこの回答ではあえて詳細を書かないでおきます。

Answer (score 0):

このようなプログラムでは、「この文字列を表示して（出力）」や「ここで文字列が打ち込まれる（入力）」をプログラムとして書く必要があります。今回の場合出力を行っているのが `printf` 関数で、入力を行っているのが `scanf` 関数です。

今回のプログラムでは次のように計算結果を変数に代入することはしています。

```c
ans_int = sum_int(a, b);
```

しかしその結果を出力していないので、何も出力されていません。`printf` 関数を使って変数 `ans_int` の値を出力してあげてください。