# 要素の平均と和を返す関数。

Tags: c

0番目からｎ−1番めまでの要素の平均と和について出力したいのですが、やりかたがイマイチわかりません。
１＋２＋３＋４＋・・・＋ｎのように順番に足していくプログラムの書き方は理解しているつもりなのですが、端末にランダムに数字を入力させ、その和と平均を出力させるプログラムを書く方法がわかりませんでした。
以下のようにプログラムを入力したのですが、おそらく、sumIntArrayの部分が間違っていると思われるのと、/........./の部分に何をプログラムするべきかわかりませんでした。

```
void readIntArray(int a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%d番目?",i=i+1);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("%d",a[i]);
}

void sumIntArray(int a[], int size)
{
int sum,i;
for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
sum=sum+i;
}
return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
  int data[100], n, sum;
  double average;

  printf("n=? ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  readIntArray(data, n);

  sum = sumIntArray(data, n);
  printf("sum = %d\n", sum);

/......................./
  return 0;
}
```

実行例は、次のようになれば良いです。

```
$ ./a.out
n=? 5
0 番目? 2
1 番目? 3
2 番目? 5
3 番目? 7
4 番目? 11
sum = 28
average = 5.600000
```

Comment: 過去に [合計を求めるプログラムに関する質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60113) をされていますが、こちらの結果と要素数が分かっていれば、平均を求めるのも難しくない気がします。 / 「sumIntArrayの部分が間違っていると思われる」のは何故なのか (実行しても結果が違う  or エラーになる 等) をもっと具体的に書いてみるとよいかもしれません。

Comment: 質問のコードはコンパイルエラーになるため、私達には現在の実行結果すら確認できません。「やり方がわからない」と言いますが、現在のコードはCのコードとして間違っている部分があるため、例えやり方がわかっても動くようにはならないと思います。まずは、あなたが今、躓いていることをはっきりさせてください。コンパイル時にエラー出るのか、期待している結果とは違う表示がされるのか、合計までは正しく出るが平均のみ未実装で出ないなのか、そういうことを**質問に明記してください**。もし、あなたの手元でコンパイルが成功しているのであれば、貼り付けの際に間違ったのかも知れませんが、私達にはそれを知ることすらできません。今のコンパイルすらできないコードでは、まずはコンパイル出来るように正しいCのコードを書いてくださいとしか言い様がありません。

Answer (score 1):

以下の様な点を元にプログラムを見直してください。

- 前質問 [要素を逆順に格納する手続きについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60235/26370) に付いた @metropolis さんのコメントと同じ内容
  `readIntArray()`関数内の`printf("%d番目?",i=i+1);`は`printf("%d番目?", i+1);`
- `readIntArray()`関数最後の`printf("%d",a[i])`は意味不明
- `sumIntArray()`関数の定義と処理が間違い

  - 戻り値は`void`ではなく`int`
  - 変数`sum`を0で初期化していない
  - `for`ループ内の処理がインデックス値の加算になっているのをデータの加算に修正
- `double`値で表現される平均を得るためには、合計値とデータ数を`double`でキャストして計算
- `double`値を`printf()`で表示するための指定方法は、使用している参考書を見るとかWebで検索